# How to use compression algorithm for image compression i.e LZ4 , LZMA , ZLIB swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to compress image using above lossless algorithms, but these algorithm works on data but not on image data. is there anyway to compress image using these algorithms 
here is a code

```
    var org = UIImage(named: "Dragon.jpg")
    var res: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(org!)!

    print("Image before Compressing")
    print(res.count)
    print(res)
    orignal.image =  UIImage(data: res)


    res = res.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE)!

    print("Image After Compressing")
    print(res.count)
    print(res)


    res = res.decompress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE)!

    print("Image After Decompressing")
    print(res)
    print(res.count)


    compress.image =
        UIImage(data: res)
```

**OutPut**
Image before Compressing

1915549

1915549 bytes

Image After Compressing

1935259

1935259 bytes

Image After Decompressing

1915549

1915549 bytes

Comment: Why don't you use JPEG to compress your image? How would you compress an image and at the same time keep all its quality? Just use JPEG at maximum quality

Comment: @LeoDabus any Example ?

Comment: There *are* lossless image compression formats, such as PNG.

Comment: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)`

Comment: @LeoDabus let me check it

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation() returns the data in the PNG file format, which is already compressed. Compressing compressed data again usually does not make it smaller, and often larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compress that data using this algorithm and from that data make image .

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

So U will get that image .
Use This If You Want To Compress Image :- (Resolution changing)

```
 func compressImage(image:UIImage) -> Data? {   

    var actualHeight : CGFloat = image.size.height
    var actualWidth : CGFloat = image.size.width
    let maxHeight : CGFloat = 2732 .0
    let maxWidth : CGFloat = 2048.0
    var imgRatio : CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio : CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    var compressionQuality : CGFloat = 0.5

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
        else{
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            compressionQuality = 1
        }
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    guard let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality)else{
        return nil
    }
    return imageData
}
```

Comment: But using this , The result of these compression algorithms is different . instead of compressing the size of of data increased

Comment: Forget about zipping your image. If you need to compress its data just use JPEG representation. If you need lossless quality and don't care about the size use PNG `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

Comment: Can u explain Your Problem with code ? And  what Problem u facing /

Comment: Why are you decompressing again make image with compressed data

Comment: @Amey its my requirement but the point is after compression the result is same Why ???

Comment: Check if above Code help

Comment: @Amey thanks for Helping but  i need decompression also anyway thanks